# next auth coinbase provider using prisma adapter doesn't add Account error created_at in data.created_at for type AccountUncheckedCreateInput

Tags: provider, prisma, coinbase-api, next-auth

Seems like one data object in AccountUncheckedCreateInput is missing:
data.created_at

Invalid p.account.create() invocation in

```
16 },
17 updateUser: ({ id, ...data }) => p.user.update({ where: { id }, data }),
18 deleteUser: (id) => p.user.delete({ where: { id } }),
→ 19 linkAccount: (data) => p.account.create({
data: {
xxx
}
})

Unknown arg created_at in data.created_at for type AccountUncheckedCreateInput. Available args:

type AccountUncheckedCreateInput {
id?: String
userId: String
type: String
provider: String
providerAccountId: String
refresh_token?: String | Null
access_token?: String | Null
expires_at?: Int | Null
token_type?: String | Null
scope?: String | Null
id_token?: String | Null
session_state?: String | Null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so to solve it a position in Object Account prisma model (or any) needs to be added:
created_at Int?

then npx prisma db push and npx prisma generate, after this it works, so the main model needs to be replaced to be:

```
model Account {
id String @id @default(cuid())
userId String
type String
created_at Int?
provider String
providerAccountId String
refresh_token String?
access_token String?
expires_at Int?
token_type String?
scope String?
id_token String?
session_state String?
user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

@@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
```